# Add transactional variables to custom phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, transactional-mail

I am trying to build a PDF417 barcode generation for Order transactional email and for that I need some information from the order to pass to custom built phtml file, so javascript there can build a barcode image.

I am including custom phtml file into transactional template like this

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/pdf417.phtml' }}
```

and I would like to be able to pass things like

```
{{var=$order.getCustomerName()}}
```

to this file, or get customer name directly in phtml file.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/pdf417.phtml' order=$order }}
```

this will allow you to pass the order object to the template file.
from here, you can call on the methods for the order object.
you can get the order object in the template file like this:

```
$order = $this->getOrder()
```